# from flask_session import Session produces ImportError: cannot import name want_bytes

Tags: python, flask, flask-session

I'm trying to use flask_session for redis based sessions and getting the following error:

Using the following

```
from flask_session import Session
```

Produces error:

```
shadow_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
shadow_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
shadow_1  |     worker.init_process()
shadow_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
shadow_1  |     self.load_wsgi()
shadow_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
shadow_1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
shadow_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
shadow_1  |     self.callable = self.load()
shadow_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
shadow_1  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
shadow_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
shadow_1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
shadow_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
shadow_1  |     __import__(module)
shadow_1  |   File "/usr/src/app/app.py", line 13, in <module>
shadow_1  |     from flask_session import Session
shadow_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_session/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
shadow_1  |     from .sessions import NullSessionInterface, RedisSessionInterface, \
shadow_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_session/sessions.py", line 23, in <module>
shadow_1  |     from itsdangerous import Signer, BadSignature, want_bytes
shadow_1  | ImportError: cannot import name want_bytes
```

Comment: Seems to be a recently introduced issue: https://github.com/fengsp/flask-session/issues/89

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Please provide some code, What are you trying to do? What you tried so far? What you expect?

Comment: Actually, flask_session depends on itsdangerous and recently it got updated after 3 years so it changes the way it's importing Signer, BadSignation, want_bytes.

Comment: to make it work, Go to the folders where these modules are installed and into flask_session change the import from **itsdangerous import Signer, BadSignature, want_bytes**
to - 
**from itsdangerous import Signer, BadSignature** and 
**from itsdangerous.encoding import want_bytes**

Answer (score 2):

flask_session package has a dependency on package ItsDangerous which had a new release after 3 years of inactivity, and it changed its API and now breaks Flask_session.

Try adding to requirements.txt a version 0.24

requirements.txt:

```
ItsDangerous==0.24
```